# How can I filter a list of id's by comparing values of the same id's in a different table?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following SQL Postgres database table:

```
    id      fid               val
401411677   3765    2019-09-06 00:00:00.000
401411677   3782    2019-09-06 00:00:00.000
401413382   3765    2019-12-20 00:00:00.000
401413382   3782    2019-12-23 00:00:00.000
401412111   3765    2019-09-20 00:00:00.000
401412111   3782    2019-09-20 00:00:00.000
```

In the above, an `fid = 3765` represents the `FirstDate` and and `fid=3782` is the `SecondDate`.

I am trying to filter out all the id's where the `FirstDate` and `SecondDate` are equal.

So in the above example, the output would be only `401413382`, since it's FirstDate and SecondDate values are not the same, but for the other id's they are the same.

Comment: Hii do you mean where a fid is not available? Can assume it is always available :)
And only has the two values 3765 and 3782

Comment: Ahh nope, they will always have both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using two subqueries:

```
select distinct t.id from tbl t where 
 (select min(t1.val) from tbl t1 where t1.id = t.id and t1.fid = 3765) !=
 (select min(t1.val) from tbl t1 where t1.id = t.id and t1.fid = 3782)
```

[See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/bQM-EQFh)

Comment: Thank you @ajax1234, much appreciated. 

It works! In the first `where` statement, can I add an extra `where id in (select id from id where sid = 2403) and....`

Comment: @user21641220 Yes, like so: `select distinct t.id from tbl t where 
 (select min(t1.val) from tbl t1 where t1.id = t.id and t1.fid = 3765) !=
 (select min(t1.val) from tbl t1 where t1.id = t.id and t1.fid = 3782) and id in (select id from id where sid = 2403) and ...`